# How to assign a touch pad to control a specific monitor

Tags: touchpad

This is a problem regarding using dual monitor and a touch pad(tablet pen) input.

I've just bought an ASUS Eee Note EA800( http://www.asus.com/Eee/Eee_Note/Eee_Note_EA800/ ). When connecting it to the PC, the EA800 can act as a wacom touchpad. However, I find that the touchpad controls the whole screen area of my **both** monitors, but I just want it to control only screen 1. How can I do that?

My monitor layout is:

[image]

OS: Windows 7 x64 professional.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figure it out. Just in Control Panel -> Pen Tablet Properties section(installed by the EA800 bundled Wacom driver).

Pen Tablet Properties -> [Pen] tab -> [Details...] -> Screen Area .
[image]